# Hartle chaper 11 Missing partial microposts/_micropost

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, render

I'm new to rails but I've been having continual issues in Chapter 11 of hartls tutorial, currently the `<%= render 'shared/feed' %>` gives

```
Missing partial microposts/_micropost with {:locale=>[:en], :formats=>[:html], :variants=>[], :handlers=>[:erb, :builder, :raw, :ruby, :coffee, :jbuilder]}.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed this:

Listing 11.21: A partial for showing a single micropost.

app/views/microposts/_micropost.html.erb

```
<li id="micropost-<%= micropost.id %>">
  <%= link_to gravatar_for(micropost.user, size: 50), micropost.user %>
  <span class="user"><%= link_to micropost.user.name, micropost.user %></span>
  <span class="content"><%= micropost.content %></span>
  <span class="timestamp">
    Posted <%= time_ago_in_words(micropost.created_at) %> ago.
  </span>
</li>
```

Create this partial and everything will be fine

Comment: <%= render @microposts %> wouldn't work either so I had to use the answer I found here (which worked) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13485344/ruby-on-rails-tutorial-by-m-hartl-chapter-10-2-1-undefined-local-variable-or

Comment: That's weird, because error message states that system is looking for `microposts/_micropost` partial. It usually happens when you do something like `render @microposts`. And the error also says that the partial it is looking for is not there. So either you misspelled it's name, or created it in the wrong folder, @Taz12

Comment: YOU DID IT!!! Thank you soo much, I spelled it _microposts.html.erb instead of _micropost.html.erb You are awesome/I'm an idiot :)